# Send a Json which is like key:{key:value,key:[]} with Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am new to using Volley and parsing complex Json.

I have Json like:

```
"timings": {
    "summary": "Mon-Fri 9am-6pm",
    "detail": [
        "Mon 9am-6pm",
        "Tue 9am-6pm",
        "Wed 9am-6pm",
        "Thu 9am-6pm",
        "Fri 9am-6pm"
     ]
}
```

I am not sure how to send it. I have tried to search for solutions but no luck.
Some help will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Gson library.
And with Gson create class with name of Timings and contain 2 variables .

```
data class Timings ( val summery: String , val details : List<String>)
val gson: Gson()
time = gson.fromJson(jsonString,Timings::class.java)
```

Other way is use Json Object and json array to parse it manually